# Problem with running Kernel in IPython console

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I have a problem with the Spyder software of Python(version 4.0.1) regarding the running kernels in the IPython Console. Accordingly, I have tried many ways to resolve the issue like running some commands in Anaconda prompt or set the settings to the default mode. I even updated the version of my anaconda and the spyder. Nevertheless, nothing has been changed and the issue still exists.

This is the error I am receiving:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in
>   _run_module_as_main "**main**", mod_spec) File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>   exec(code, run_globals) File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console__main__.py",
>   line 11, in  start.main() File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py",
>   line 287, in main import_spydercustomize() File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py",
>   line 39, in import_spydercustomize import spydercustomize File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 24, in  from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython__init__.py", line
>   56, in  from .terminal.embed import embed File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py",
>   line 14, in  from IPython.core.magic import Magics, magics_class,
>   line_magic File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\magic.py",
>   line 20, in  from . import oinspect File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py",
>   line 30, in  from IPython.lib.pretty import pretty File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py",
>   line 82, in  import datetime File "C:\Users\mahkam\datetime.py", line
>   4 ^ SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple‑quoted string literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to rename or remove this file

`C:\Users\mahkam\datetime.py`

That's because that file is using the same name of Python internal module and that confuses other modules that depend on it.

Comment: Thanks a million. I removed the mentioned file and now everything is all right.

Comment: Great! Then please mark my answer as correct by clicking on the green check sign on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a quoting error

```
File "C:\Users\mahkam\datetime.py", line 4 ^ SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple‑quoted string literal
```

Check out your datetime.py

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. Thanks a lot.